# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method gps on channel top.kikt/gps)

Tags: flutter, dart, gps, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement https://pub.dev/packages/gps. But while using it it is throwing  following exception-
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method gps on channel top.kikt/gps)
what is this exception and how to fix it.
note -I can not use other libraries it is necessary to implement this library.

i wrote this code to access current position but this piece of code returning null to me
var  position = await Gps.currentGps();

build.gradle info

```html
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

```html
 var position = await Gps.currentGps();
```

manifest permission I added-

```html
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop the running project

and run the command -

1)flutter clean

2)flutter pub get

and run the app again